# How to speed up download unity asset

Tags: unity-game-engine

I usually download assets on Unity Assets store.It's not really large but the speed of download in unity is too slow and it takes me alot of time.Is there any way to speed up it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how fast your internet is. If the problem is NOT your internet speed the problem could be one of the following below.

*1)* You computer has **multiple network adapters enabled** and that could be the problem. If you have **two or more Network Adapters** installed on your computer, **disable** one of them. For example, your computer usually comes with on-board Ethernet port(internet cable connected to your computer) and a wifi adapter if it is a laptop. If you are **only using wifi**, go to the **Control Panel** and **disable Ethernet network card** but **leave the wifi card enabled**.

If you are using Ethernet port(internet cable connected to your computer), go to the **Control Panel** and **disable the wifi adapter**. There is a conflict between the too.

*2)* If you have the TeamViewer software installed, **uninstall** it too.

*3)* **VMware** could be the problem too. If **VMware is installed** on your computer, **uninstall** it and then test the download again.

*4)* Disable **Internet protocol Version 6** as there could a conflict.

I had thesame before but the first solution worked. So solution 1 is likely to be the culprit.
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/asset-store-very-slow-with-unity-4.158660/page-2